# spark-submit job is not working on cluster mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to execute a python file using spark-submit on cluster mode. Can someone suggest me to What I need to do before doing that as its giving error?

I have tried master as yarn and without cluster mode its running fine.

`test_cluster.py`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark= 
SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("yarn").getOrCreate()
```

execute command:

```
 spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test_cluster.py
```

YARN log:

> Application application_1557254378595_0020 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1557254378595_0020_000002 exited with
>   exitCode: 13 Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-05-07
>   22:20:22.422]Exception from container-launch. Container id:
>   container_1557254378595_0020_02_000001 Exit code: 13 [2019-05-07
>   22:20:22.424]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 13. Error
>   file: prelaunch.err. Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err : Last 4096
>   bytes of stderr : 19/05/07 22:20:21 ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: User application
>   exited with status 1 19/05/07 22:20:21 ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:498)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:815)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:814)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:839)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application
>   exited with 1 at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:106) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner.main(PythonRunner.scala) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)

Comment: Are you running the spark job in a standalone cluster? If yes, it's documented that cluster mode isn't supported for python applications. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit

Comment: I am running on GCP cluster machine.
Master - 1
worker - 3

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *cluster* deployment mode is not available for Python applications, as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit).

You can try *client* deployment-mode.